# How Can i capture XHR - Response for a click action using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible capture Developer tools(F12) - Network - XHR - Response for a button click  using selenium webdriver.

In the below image , I need to capture the ID value

[image: XHR Response for my application]

Comment: Why do you want to do this  and what have you tried? Any code ? Any google searches ?

Comment: one of my requirement is to  get the ID value from response Json and i tried to retrieve it using "network.responsereceieved" using selenium and java. but no luck

Comment: You need to make a xhr request to required API using java code and use the response to capture the required value from the response data.